# How to download a file with wget that starts with a word and it has a specific extension?

Tags: bash, download, filenames, wget, tar

Im trying to do a *bash* script and i need to download certain files with *wget*
like *`libfat-nds-1.0.11.tar.bz2`* but after some times the version of this file may change so i would like to download a file that start with *libfatnds* and ends in *.tar.bz2* .Is this possible with wget?

Comment: No. `wget` doesn't support _wildcards_!

Comment: Thank you for you reply i didnt know wget doesn't support wildcards :),also i dont think this question is off topic as it ask if a program has a certain feature making a live example. Please post your answer again so i can chose it as the best .have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only `wget`, it can be achieved by specifying filename with wildcards in the list of accepted extensions.

```
wget -r -np -nd --accept='libfat-nds-*.tar.bz2'
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i was searching for!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that HTTP doesn't support wildcard downloads
. But if there is content listing enabled on the server or you have a index.html containing the available file names you could download that, extract the file name you need and then download the file with wget.

Something in this order

1. Download the index with curl
2. Use grep and/or sed to extract the exact file name
3. Download the file with wget (or curl)

If you pipe the commands you can do it on one line.